# Can Shortest Job First Scheduling be subject to convoy effect?

Tags: process, operating-system, scheduling

Look at the below table for example :
[image]

Look at the **Non-Preemptive SJF** table
Suppose if the ***burst time*** of process **P1** was a very large number compared to **7**, the processes **P3,P2 and P4** have to wait for a large amount of time till **P1** frees the CPU. 
No book or article that I've read mentions of SJF being a subject to convoy effect?
 Why not?

Comment: Mention what ? Shortest Job First minimizes the average waiting time. If the system is preemptive then it minimizes the waiting time compared to other algorithms, the same goes for non-preemptive systems.